# Force a WHM / CPanel Backup via SSH

Tags: backup

How to generate forcely backup of all account in WHM/cPanel. Actuly i am want to generate full backup of my all cpanel account, and want to remove backup drive from server so i don't want to scheduled it.

So suggest me terminal script coomand that can generate backup.

Comment: What research have you done for yourself on this? SF is not a script writing service.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: i got its solution http://www.itsadam.co.uk/force-a-whm-cpanel-backup-via-ssh/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate an account backup from shell, you can use [/scripts/pkgacct](https://documentation.cpanel.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=362469) script.

You generate full account backup with

```
/scripts/pkgacct username
```

If you would like to backup all the accounts on the server, you can do the following.

Go to /var/cpanel/users directory, which holds definiton files for all cPanel users, with

```
cd /var/cpanel/users
```

Run the backup script for all accounts on the server, and store backups to /some/path folder.

```
for i in *; do /scripts/pkgacct $i /some/path; done
```

Comment: i got its solution http://www.itsadam.co.uk/force-a-whm-cpanel-backup-via-ssh/